# MongoDB Aggregate `$group` and array names

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a kind of problem with my mongoDB query (using `aggregate`).
And I would be delighted to get some clue...

**Below my MongoCollection :**
Note that `KLLS` is either `a`, `b` or `c`, and there are 3 `types`: `processus`, `work` and `viewing`.

```
{_id: 1, KLLS: "a", action: "A", type: "Processus", date: Date, other:"abc" }
{_id: 2, KLLS: "b", action: "B", type: "Processus", date: Date }
{_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "C", type: "Work"     , date: Date, other:"xyz" }
{_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "D", type: "Work"     , date: Date }
{_id: 5, KLLS: "a", action: "E", type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
{_id: 6, KLLS: "b", action: "F", type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
...
```

**What I'd like to achieve with the query:**

```
[ { 
    _id: { KLLS: "a"},
    Processus: [[action: "A", date: "Date", other: "abc"]]
    Work:      [[action: "C", date: "Date"]]
    Viewing:   [[action: "E", date: "Date"]]
  },
  { 
    _id: { KLLS: "b"},
    Processus: [[action: "B", date: "Date"]]
    Work:      [[action: "D", date: "Date", other: "xyz"]]
    Viewing:   [[action: "F", date: "Date"]]
  }
]
```

**At this moment, my (failing) query is:**

```
db.collection('events').aggregate([
    {$match: {
        KLLS: {$in: something}
    }},
    {$group: {
        _id: {
            klls: "$KLLS",
            type: "$type"
        }, 
        array: { 
            $push: "$$ROOT"
        }
    }}
])
```

However, I have one problem : It makes a `composite id` but I don't have 3 nicely named `arrays`...

```
[
 {   
     _id: { KLLS: "a", type: "Processus" },
     array: [[action: "A", date: "Date", other: "abc"]]
 },
 { 
     _id: { KLLS: "a", type: "Work" },
     array: [[action: "C", date: "Date"]]
 },
 { 
     _id: { KLLS: "a", type: "Viewing" },
     array: [[action: "E", date: "Date"]]
 }, 
 { 
     _id: { KLLS: "b", type: "Processus" },
     array: [[action: "B", date: "Date"]]
 },
 { 
     _id: { KLLS: "b", type: "Work" },
     array: [[action: "D", date: "Date", other: "xyz"]]
 }, 
 { 
     _id: { KLLS: "b", type: "Viewing" },
     array: [[action: "F", date: "Date"]]
 },
 ...
]
```

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks.

---

**********************  EDIT ************************

Let's imagine the very same collection contains also:

```
{_id: 1, KLLS: "a", action: "A",  type: "Processus", date: Date }
{_id: 2, KLLS: "b", action: "B",  type: "Processus", date: Date }
{_id: 5, KLLS: "a", action: "E",  type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
{_id: 6, KLLS: "b", action: "F",  type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
   ...
{_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work"     , date: Date, key:"123" }
{_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work"     , date: Date, key: "123" }
{_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work"     , date: Date, key:"456" }
{_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work"     , date: Date, key: "456" }
   ...
```

(Note that for type `Work`, I got another `key`).

**Thanks to your help, at this moment, I got:**

```
[{ 
    _id: { KLLS: "a"},
    Processus: [   everything is ok    ],
    Viewing:   [   everything is ok    ],
    Details:   [   everything is ok    ],
    Work:      [
        {_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"123" }
        {_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "123" }
        {_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"456" }
        {_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "456" }
    ]
...
```

**Whereas, the final result I'd like is:**

```
[{
    _id: { KLLS: "a"},
    Processus: [   everything is ok    ],
    Viewing:   [   everything is ok    ],
    Details:   [   everything is ok    ],
    Work:      [
        subArrayByKey [ // key = 123
            {_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"123" },
            {_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "123" }
        ],
        subArrayByKey [ // key = 456
            {_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"456" },
            {_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "456" }
        ]
    ]
...
```

I tried doing (1) a kind of `nested $group` and also (2) to add criteria into your first $group to make a `composite id` (like I tried at the very beginning). But the `$eq` is embarrassing me...

```
{ $match: { something } },
{ $sort: { by date } },
{ $group: { what you wrote } },
{ $group: { a nested $group I tried } }
```

Finally, and not surprisingly, I failed... the return query is no empty..
If I may.. do you have any clue... ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `$cond` operator with `$push` to add values to the array that match the condition.

`$cond` is a ternary operator and in the below example the original document is added to the array when the condition is met and a dummy value `false` is added to the array when the condition is not met.

In the final `$project` stage, the dummy `false` entries in the arrays are removed using the `setDifference` operator.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
         "_id" : "$KLLS",
         "Processus": {
             "$push": { 
                 "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$type", "Processus"]}, "$$ROOT", false]
             }
         },
         "Work": {
             "$push": {
                 "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$type","Work"]}, "$$ROOT", false]
             }
         },
         "Viewing": {
             "$push": {
                 "$cond": [{"$eq" : ["$type","Viewing"]}, "$$ROOT", false]
             }
         },
         "Details": {"$push" : "$other"}
    }},

    {"$project": {
         "_id": 0, 
         "KLLS": "$_id",
         "Processus": {"$setDifference": ["$Processus", [false]]},
         "Work":      {"$setDifference": ["$Work",      [false]]},
         "Viewing":   {"$setDifference": ["$Viewing",   [false]]},
         "Details": 1
    }}
])
```

Also, to add just few fields to the array, you can try something like below.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {"$group": {
         "_id": "$KLLS",
         "Processus": {
             "$push": { 
                 "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$type","Processus"]}, {"action": "$action","other": "$other"}, false]
             }
          },
          "Work": {
              "$push": {
                  "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$type","Work"]}, {"action": "$action","other": "$other"}, false]
              }
          },
          "Viewing":{
              "$push": {
                  "$cond": [{"$eq": ["$type","Viewing"]}, {"action": "$action","other": "$other"}, false]
              }
          },
          "Details": {"$push": "$other"}
    }},

    {"$project": { 
         "_id": 0, 
         "KLLS": "$_id",
         "Processus": {"$setDifference": ["$Processus", [false]]},
         "Work":      {"$setDifference": ["$Work",      [false]]},
         "Viewing":   {"$setDifference": ["$Viewing",   [false]]},
         "Details": 1
    }}
])
```

Comment: First, thank you very much. It works _almost_ like a charm!
Is it possible also to create thanks to `Group` another array (like `Processus`, `Work` and `Viewing`) called `Details' which contains `other: "abc"` taken from my record with `action: "A"` (see my initial post). Thanks again: query in MongoDB and agregate are not that easy...

Comment: Thanks again. I edit my initial post for a final question concerning a `nested group` or `composite id`. It is very kind of you to help me so much!

Comment: Could you please post the latest edited portion as a separate question? It will attract more users.

Comment: Just done! [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006027/mongodb-group-inside-a-group-by-key). Thanks again!