# Mongodb - $group inside a $group (by 'key')

Tags: mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

As proposed by [4J41](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1611791/4j41) (thanks to him/her), I split my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39947421/mongodb-agregate-group-and-array-names) into a new one.

I have one last problem with my mongoDB query. And I would be delighted to get some help...

**Below my MongoCollection :**
Note that `KLLS` is either `a`, `b` or `c`, and there are 3 `types` : `processus`, `work`, `viewing` and, for some, a special `key`(only for `work`).

```
{_id: 1, KLLS: "a", action: "A", type: "Processus", date: Date }
{_id: 2, KLLS: "b", action: "B", type: "Processus", date: Date }
{_id: 5, KLLS: "a", action: "E", type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
{_id: 6, KLLS: "b", action: "F", type: "Viewing"  , date: Date }
...
{_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"123" }
{_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "123" }
{_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"456" }
{_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "456" }
...
```

**Currently, the query is (thanks again to 4J41 user) :**

```
db.collection('events').aggregate([
   { $match: { KLLS: {$in: something} } },
   { $sort: { date: 1 } },
   { '$group': {
     '_id': '$KLLS',
     'Processus': {'$push': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$type', 'Processus']}, '$$ROOT', false]}},
     'Works': {'$push': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$type', 'Works']}, '$$ROOT', false]}},
     'Viewings': {'$push': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$type', 'Viewings']}, '$$ROOT', false]}},
     'Details': {'$push': {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$action', 'Stuff']}, '$$ROOT', false]}}
          }},
    {'$project': {
      '_id': 0,
      'KLLS': '$_id',
      'Processus': { '$setDifference': ['$Processus', [false]] },
      'Works': { '$setDifference': ['$Works', [false]] },
      'Viewings': { '$setDifference': ['$Viewings', [false]] },
      'Details': { '$setDifference': ['$Details', [false]] }
          }}
        ]
      )
```

---

*I edited from here changing some order/wording to make it clearer*

---

**At this time I got:**

```
[ { _id: { KLLS: 'a'},
  Processus: [   everything is ok    ]
  Viewing:   [   everything is ok    ]
  Details:   [   everything is ok    ]
  Work:      [
   {_id: 3, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"123" }
   {_id: 4, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "123" }
   {_id: 5, KLLS: "a", action: "AB", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"456" }
   {_id: 6, KLLS: "b", action: "XY", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "456" }
            ]
  }]
...
```

The only last problem is into `Work`. Currently, I have a list composed of `4` records (`_id`: `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`). See above. **Whereas I'd like to get subgroups by `key` like below** (caution: I do not know the `value` of the `key`).

```
[ { _id: { KLLS: 'a'},
  Processus: [ everything is ok ]
  Viewing:   [ everything is ok ]
  Details:   [   everything is ok    ]
  Work:      [
     [ // this a "$group" by key 
         {_id: ..., KLLS: "...", action: "...", type: "Work", date: Date, key:"123" }
         {_id: ..., KLLS: "...", action: "...", type: "Work", date: Date, key: "123" }
     ]
     [ // this a "$group" by key 
         {_id: ..., KLLS: "...", action: "...", type: "Work", date:..., key:"456" }
         {_id: ..., KLLS: "...", action: "...", type: "Work", date:..., key: "456" }
     ]
]
...
```

I tried doing (1) a kind of nested `$group` and also (2) to add criteria into first $group to make a composite `id`, but it doesn't seem to work (empty query result).

Do you have any idea how to resolve this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add nested `$cond`to filter the keys 123 or 456. Then, a final `$project` stage can be used to construct the array.

```
db.events.aggregate([
    {"$group":
        {   "_id":"$KLLS",
            "Processus":{"$push":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$type","Processus"]},'$$ROOT',false]}},
            "Work123":
                {"$push":
                    {"$cond":
                        [
                            {"$eq":["$type","Work"]},
                            {"$cond":
                                [
                                    {"$eq":["$key","123"]},
                                    '$$ROOT',
                                    false
                                ]
                            },
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                },
            "Work456":
                {"$push":
                    {"$cond":
                        [
                            {"$eq":["$type","Work"]},
                            {"$cond":
                                [
                                    {"$eq":["$key","456"]},
                                    '$$ROOT',
                                    false
                                ]
                            },
                            false
                        ]
                    }
                },
            "Viewing":{"$push":{"$cond":[{"$eq":["$type","Viewing"]},'$$ROOT',false]}}
        }
    },
    {"$project": { "_id":0, "KLLS":"$_id", "Processus":{"$setDifference":["$Processus",[false]]},
        "123":{"$setDifference":["$Work123",[false]]},
        "456":{"$setDifference":["$Work456",[false]]},
        "Viewing":{"$setDifference":["$Viewing",[false]]}
        }
    },
    {"$project": { "KLLS":1, "Processus":1, "Work" : [{"123" : "$123"}, {"456" : "$456"}],"Viewing":1}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks, but the wanted output was not clear. Sorry, I edited it. I try to get inside `Work` as many `subarrays` as I have `key` (I do not know the `value' of `key`)..

Comment: I'm very sorry to call you. But i was wondering if you could give me one (very) last advice. See my comment above. Thank you very much.

Comment: @nerotulip : In this case, where values have to considered as fields, you might want to look at Map reduce. Not sure, if aggregation will help you accomplish this. Operators `$arrayToObject` and '$$objectToArray' which may help you accomplish this, are not implemented yet. I am sorry, this is beyond me. :(

Comment: I'm not sure we need to go 'that far' :-) Indeed, as you succeeded in filling `Work` subdoc with all records with `type` = `work`. The idea is now, inside `Work` subdoc, to `$group` by `key`. **I don't need to considered `values` as `fields`**. What I try is something a bit like `$group`: {  `_id` : { `type` : `$type`, `key` : `$key`}}...